# Find button class with Selenium on Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, test-strategy

I scrapping the marketplace from this URL https://www.tokopedia.com/sunxin

I want to get the data from the `button` called `Info Toko`, if user click this will shown a pop up content:
[image]
[image]

The original source code for this button is:

```
<button class="css-rhf1fq-unf-btn e1ggruw00"><span>Info Toko</span></button>
```

I've tried to get the element by `xpath`, `classname`, `link text`, but still not working.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Info Toko')
```

Always get error message like this
[image]

Any ideas how to get this element?

Comment: Accept my answer if it is helped you

Answer (score 2):

Try by using `xpath` selector

In which you want to change your selector code as shown below

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-ais6tt"]//button[3]')`

This will work

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use a method read its documentation :

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

```
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Continue')
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Conti')
```

This two element locators identifies the element only using link text.

**In selenium a link is "an anchor tag" , an anchor tag is used wrap a href link**

in your case its a button tag and not a anchor 'a' tag, so link text method won't work

**use xpath , css or class**

**xpath:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Info Toko"]')
```

**css:**

css to find using class

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.css-rhf1fq-unf-btn.e1ggruw00')
```

**class:**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-rhf1fq-unf-btn e1ggruw00')
```